# Subset regression in Python via exhaustive search

Tags: python, r

Using Python what is the best way to perform an exhaustive search for the best subsets of the variables in x for predicting y in
linear regression?  R, for example, has a package called [leaps](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaps/index.html) which does so using an efficient branch-and-bound algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are quite a few R packages that do not have equivalent Python packages. R is much more mature language when it comes to statistics.

I frequently use [RPy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2) to incorporate R packages in my Python work. It seems like it would work for your desired leaps package as well.